# heatsink for two LM4780TA chips

Tags: heatsink

What heatsink thermal resistance is need for two [LM4780TA](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4780.pdf) chips? The specs are junction to case 0.8C/W and case to sink 0.2C/W. Is more info required?

Comment: "Is more info required?" - yes, you also need to determine how much heat the ICs will be dissipating in your application, and the max ambient temperature, in addition to datasheet parameters (it's helpful to post a link so others don't have to google)

Comment: Power dissipation, ambient temperature, maximum junction temperature (you might be happy to operate at degraded lifetime, or not)?

Comment: If you look at a [datasheet for the chip](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4780.pdf) you will find the necessary information. Using a mica washer for electrical insulation from the heatsink may be a good idea. If it is possible to have a fan blowing air over the heatsink, you can use a smaller heatsink.

Comment: The minimum is to tell us what power consumption you will have to dissipate on each chip. An upper limit for this value can be deduced from the supply voltages you'll use and the load impedance.

Answer (score 0):

The chip is rated for 125W which depends on Tj=150'C
Generally it should not exceed Tj=80'C for reliable long life.
 Thus if you derate to 100W X two chips @30'C the temp rise is 50'C for 200W so your heat sink must be Rca= 50/200=0.25'C/W

This is just the sink interface temp.
Lowest cheap method is used CPU heat sink (0.1'CW) and fan and suitable silver grease, and clamps.

Thermal resistance from jcn to case to sink =0.8+0.2=1

- So overall Rja is 1'C/W + 0.1'C = 1.1 'C /W.
- Rja=0.25'C/W is not possible with this case design.
- Keep IC's separated as far as possible.
- Power out RMS sustained must be reduced linearly to lower Tj of junction but peak power is Ok for short durations.
- These two IC's can generate more heat at 50% efficiency than a CPU so you need a PS with twice the total audio power you want.

Comment: *"Keep IC's separated as far as possible."* It might be worth pointing out that that means HCHHCH rather than CHHHHC (H=heatsink, C=chip) if both are mounted on the same heatsink.

Comment: For an internal heat sink, I would use the following numbers:
Ambient temp: 40 ºC
Max temp (internal heat sink): 80 ºC (pretty darn toasty!)
Load impedance: 4 Ω
Crest factor: 14 dB
Supply voltage: ±35 V
Amp channels per heat sink: 1 Is ther a formula i could pulg the numbers into and get the thermal resistance so I could buy the proper heatsink? formual